# Bonobo Can't Open Database File

Tags: sqlite, bonobo

I'm trying to install Bonobo on Windows 7/IIS 7/.Net 4.5 but I'm having trouble with SQLite.  I get the following error when I load up the page in a browser

```
 unable to open database file
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: unable to open database file

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[SQLiteException (0xe): unable to open database file]
   System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Open(String strFilename, SQLiteConnectionFlags connectionFlags, SQLiteOpenFlagsEnum openFlags, Int32 maxPoolSize, Boolean usePool) +731
   System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.Open() +445916
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure) +102

[EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open.]
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure) +11430327
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open() +142
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection() +97
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand(String commandText, Object[] parameters) +53
   Bonobo.Git.Server.Data.Update.AutomaticUpdater.UpdateDatabase() +444
   Bonobo.Git.Server.MvcApplication.Application_Start() +145

[HttpException (0x80004005): The underlying provider failed on Open.]
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +12962661
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +175
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +304
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +404
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +475

[HttpException (0x80004005): The underlying provider failed on Open.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +12979668
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +159
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +12819261
```

I have SQLite installed now (though, I don't think that matters... Bonobo comes with its own SQLite dlls.  I AM running on a 64 bit system.  I don't know if that has anything to do with compatability.  I've followed the installation instructions on the Bonobo site to the tee, but I still get this error and Google hasn't provided any answers for me.  Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

You should try to set the right security options for your IIS.

From http://bonobogitserver.com/install/

[image]